# Deploying the sagemaker endpoint created as a service

Tags: amazon-web-services, endpoint, amazon-sagemaker

I have trained a credit-fraud data set on AWS Sagemaker and created an endpoint of the model. Suppose I want to provide it as a service to my friend. He has some credit data and wanted to know whether the transaction is fraud or not. He wishes to use my endpoint. How do I share it?

1. Should I share my ARN for endpoint? I don't think its the right way. without a common account he won't be able to use it.
2. Or is there another way

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To share your model as an endpoint, you should use lambda and API Gateway to create your API.

1. Create an API gateway that triggers a Lambda with the HTTP POST method;
2. your lambda should instantiate the SageMaker endpoint, get the requested parameter in the event, call the SageMaker endpoint and return the predicted value. you can also create a DynamoDB to store commonly requested parameters with their answers;
3. Send the API Gateway Endpoint to your friend.

[image]

Comment: or use stepfunction?

Comment: @Cecilia can be used to orchestrate all these steps